# python selenium typing issue

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()                 # sayfa açıldıktan sonra kapanmaması için
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)      # sayfa açıldıktan sonra kapanmaması için


service = Service("./chromedriver.exe")          # kullanılacak driver'ı seçer


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=service) # Chrome ile bağdaştırma /// ***DRIVER***

    
driver.get("http://www.instagram.com") # istenilen link'i açar


input_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"_aa4b _add6 _ac4d _ap35")



input_element.send_keys("example")
```

I have wanted to write something in username area but I couldn't. When I started the code it is running until page is loaded then nothing writing.

I will add the return message under

I am getting this return:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55830/devtools/browser/788ecdf3-3c36-4668-b013-5bbb2ba04b54
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\erenu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\PYTHON\Python Kodlama Eğitimi İsmail Eren-GÜNCEL\GÜNCEL ÇALIŞMA ALANI\selenium1.py", line 105, in <module>
    input_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"_aa4b _add6 _ac4d _ap35")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\erenu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 741, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\erenu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\erenu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._aa4b _add6 _ac4d _ap35"}
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.217); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D0114D02+56194]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D00804B2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CFF276AA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CFF716D0]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CFF717EC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CFFB4D77]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CFF95EBF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7CFFB2786]

        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF8E788AA58+40]
```

Comment: find the input's "name" attribute and locate using that.  Ex: XPATH of //input[@name='name-of-the-input']   Right now you're going by style, and that's probably not unique.  Your current selector also doesn't work because the style names are separated by spaces, which means multiple.  You can't use By.CLASS_NAME in that case.  (It's expecting a single css style class name...)  You can check the 'class' attribute that way, but you should always try to find something more unique like ID, or a form element's NAME attribute.